# weird conditional test

Tags: grammar

Q: Which one is better for this test?
I think we have more than one correct answer.

- Don't you think that he would have helped you yesterday if he ----- able to?

1. were
2. could be
3. was
4. had been

Comment: Which do you think could be correct, and why?

Comment: I think "had been". The usual third conditional!

Answer (score 2):

Both **were** and **had been** could work there.  **had been** puts focus on his ability at the time, whereas **were** expands the focus to his ability in general.

> Joe: My brother didn't help me with a DIY project at our parents'
> house last week.
>
> Mike: He had to drive his daughter back to college which, as you know, is six hours away. Don't you think he would have helped you if he **had been able** to?
>
> OR:
>
> Mike: He was ill for most of the
> past year and is still not 100%, and as you know he lost his job last month, so he's been focused on finding a new one. Don't you think he would have helped you if he **were** able to?

Comment: +1 And "was" also works in modern English.

Comment: Indeed.  **was** works too, though to my ear not as well.  Hearing **was** there, it would sound time-specific to me. I'm a speaker of AmE and don't consider **were** old/antiquated. Many people I know still use that form.